# Jumping to a specific line python

Tags: python, arrays, append, text-files

I am using the following code to read a text file and create an array list out of the text found in the file. 
But currently I am reading the whole file. 
How can I read for example from line no. 16 onwards in this case?

```
            array = []
            with open(path, 'r') as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                    for action in all_actions:
                        if action in line:
                            array.append(action)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
array = []
exit_line = 16
start_line = 10
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()[start_line:]):
        for action in all_actions:
            if action in line:
                array.append(action)
        if index == exit_line - 1:
            break
```

and then to make an if condition to exit/ break at line 16 that is the index +1 .

Comment: You welcome. Can you please vote and mark the answer.

Comment: I just noticed that it does not read lines after that. The start point is perfect. But I meant it reads line 16 onwards, not only line sixteen

Comment: I've edit the code to support start point so in my example the readlines of the file will start from row 10. if you don't want to exit on a specific line just make the exit_line = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try (explanation in code comments):

```
array = []
with open('path', 'r') as f:
    # x here is a loop (lines) counter provided by the enumerate function
    for x, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        for action in all_actions:
            if action in line:
                array.append(action)
        # if the counter reaches 16 BREAK out of the loop
        if x == 16:
            print ("Line 16 exiting loop")
            break
```

Comment: It only reads line 16 this way. My question meant it reads the file from 16 onwards.

Comment: @Sam Try this (>> means new line, >>> means indentation) :>>with open('path', 'r') as f:
>>>lines = f.readlines()[16:]
>>>array = [action for line in lines for action in all_actions if action in line]
>>print(array)##### if this helps please UPVOTE